# How can I use a dot file in a bash script unix

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to install git's autocomplete (and I do not want to use Homebrew to do this), so I placed the following in my `bash_profile`

```
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  source ~/.git-completion.bash
fi
```

The `.git-completion.bash` is an install script I donwload from github, specifically:

https://github.com/git/git/raw/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

The .git-completion.bash file exists, I can see it when I run `ls -la` however, every time I open a terminal window, I see

`-bash: /Users/Username/git-completion.bash: No such file or directory`

(I do not know why it does not have  a "." in that error)

I would appreciate any guidance on how to fix this without homebrew.  Thanks

Comment: You can add a `set -x` command just before your `if`. This way you will have some trace to see what is wrong.

Comment: @Jidder why? Where is the `git-completion.bash` file located?

Comment: Use a variable rather than typing long, complicated things twice and hoping they are the same. COMPLETION="~/.git-completion.bash"; [ -f "$COMPLETION" ] && source "$COMPLETION"

Comment: Ignore my previous comment i misread the question

Comment: @AvinashRaj The file is in my home directory.

@MarkSetchell I typed in your script:
`COMPLETION="~/.git-completion.bash"; [ -f "$COMPLETION" ] && source "$COMPLETION" then
  source \.git-completion.bash
fi`

And now I get several errors:

`-bash: [-f~/.git-completion.bash]: No such file or directory`
`-bash: /Users/Username/.bash_profile: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'`
and
`-bash: /Users/Startec/.bash_profile: line 3: `fi'`

Comment: Does the file contains a `.` at the beginning?

Comment: Yes, it does when I do `ls -la` but no matter how I type my original script, the error message does not include the `.`

Comment: I assume your shell to be BASH. Are you running this in Windows or Linux? (your /Users/Username has confused me!)

Comment: Sorry, my shell is indeed BASH and I am running Mac OS X (Unix).  it is actually `Users/Startec`  I just wrote `Users/Username` to make it clear what my username is